# Tutorial for Dynamic text in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Basically I have an project where I would like to modify some text in a XML file rather than in the document itself.

I've had a Google and all the tutorials lead to AS2 which doesn't work in Flash CC. I've also downloaded some templates off ActiveDen but they are all in AS2.

Anywho is there any good starting points to do this? I'm a total noob at AS but what I'm asking for doesn't sound too hard.

Cheers,

Comment: Wait, before you start working on Flash, consider Flash will be faded out in near future, as mobile platform does not support it. Also, find tutorials in Google please.

Comment: Your question's title is quite misleading, Dynamic Text and XML Handling are two different things, search for XML articles, there are plenty of them, even tutorials on the net.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor It's for a Adwords campaign, don't really have much of a choice. 
Zhafur Like I said, most of the articles are for AS2 not 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can always Google using keywords, like writing your question's title, I found this [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/inspire-archive/december2009/articles/article5/index.html)
Try to follow step by step and I'm sure that you will learn and solve your issue.